# Fastest volume rendering algorithm for 2D depth data

Tags: glsl, opencl

I have OpenGL rendering pipline where each frame has some depth data which is 2D 8bit image. What I need is to:

1) Draw it in realtime with maximum FPS as volume object

2) Map some textute to this object

I think it should be something like this:

[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHtVV.png)

I'm wondering about peformance. Curently I'm reviewing different approaches: building isosurface with marching cubes, raytracing, volume rendering. But still dont sure what is the best approach for this task. I'm using c++, opengl, opencl, glsl.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, I don't see how volume rendering or isosurfaces come into play here. If your geometry is a 2D grid of depth values, can't you just render that pretty much directly as a mesh? The geometry is already essentially a surface, isn't it? You just need to build triangles from the points, which seems fairly trivial. Or am I missing what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes you are right, I don't have actual volume data. Just a 2d depth map and rgb texture, so what I need is probably to make a triangulation and build an isosurface based on these points.